# NO errors , console.log does not apprear before it was Uncaught TypeError: str.startsWith is not a function, str is not defined, now no errors

Tags: reactjs, undefined, setstate, startswith, ends-with

okay, so i am attempting to utilize data from the github api to make a randomized emoji "mood ring" type of thing. I noticed they have a list of images in their api for emojis. I was able to fetch from the api and stringify the data. now i am trying to filter out the http links into a new array, because their database has the links categorized by name of the emoji (ex. heart) so theres no easy way to filter them (also i'm new to coding so maybe idk :o). it was giving me errors before, such as str is not defined, or endsWith is not a function, but now there are no errors and it will not even show my console.log(result). okay anyways here's my code..thank you soso much for taking the time to read this!!!!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom'
class InfoPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
 
this.state = {
newInfo: [],
info: [],
str: [],
};
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getInfo();
  this.getEmoji();
}

//getting info from github api

getInfo = () => {

  fetch(`https://api.github.com/emojis`)
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.status === 200) {
      return response.json()
    }
    console.log('success')
  })
  .then((info) => {
    this.setState([{newInfo: info}])
   
    const str = JSON.stringify(info);
    this.setState({parsed: str})
    console.log("info",info)
  })

}

//if statement starts with htttp and ends with pngv8(meaning it's a link to a photo), push into array

getEmoji = () => {
  let result=[]
  let str = this.state.str 
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.startsWith("http") && str.endsWith('v8')) {
  result.push(str)
  console.log(result)
  } else {
    console.log("not a url")
  }
  }
}


//get array of only http links -- make sure the links works

//use math.random and attatch it to the button to reveal a random photo onClick


render() {

return (

      <div className="main">

      Which Emoji Are You?

      <br></br>
      <button type="button" >Click Here To Find Out!</button>
      </div>




  )

  }

}

export default InfoPage;
```

Comment: It seems like maybe you're expecting things to happen in a certain order when in fact they are not. `fetch` is async, so just because you call `getEmoji` after `getInfo` does not guarantee that `getInfo` has finished fetching the data.

Comment: It also seems that you have a typo because I don't see `str` updated in state anywhere.

Comment: You say that `this.state = {..., str: []}` making `str` an array. Arrays don't have a `startsWith` (strings do, but arrays don't, and str is an array in your context). Because your call to `startsWith` throws an error, the execution flow is aborted before it reaches `console.log`.